# Converting string to date or getting the current date using Zend PHP Framework 2

Tags: php, date, datetime, zend-framework

I have a controller action in which I fetch the currrent date like following:

```
    $fullDate=date("Y-m-d");
    $date = strtotime($fullDate);
    $viewModel->setVariable("currentDate",$date);
// Here I would like to pass the variable to the View and then compare it with another date ...
```

With the method above I'm getting this when I do var_dump($currentDate);

```
int(1463587200)
```

which is not what I was expecting... I need a date in format like this 2016-05-19 (year-month-day)... How can I do this the valid way???

Comment: you should look at Datetime. The official docs is here : http://php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `strtotime` is converting your formatted date into a Unix time-stamp. just remove it.

```
     $fullDate=date("Y-m-d");
     $viewModel->setVariable("currentDate",$fullDate);
```

you'll be able to compare two dates in this format `Y-m-d` without converting to time-stamp.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I mean it's just a string... ?

Comment: sure, take a look at the the date_diff example in [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date_diff.asp)